# new [] or new List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I'm just thinking about the styling and performance. Previously I used to write something like,

```
var strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3};
```

But now I tend to like this style more,

```
var strings = new [] { "a", "b", "c" }.ToList();
var ints = new [] { 1, 2, 3}.ToList();
```

I prefer the second style, but now considering - is it really worth to write it like that or maybe it's not that efficient and requires more operations?

Comment: why do you prefer the second style? I think it's less readable, especially when using `var`.

Comment: Have you tried some performace tests on it? just time it and do it a 100 times en see avarage values from that test.

Comment: I'd prefer the first version because I find it easier to read for humans.

Comment: I think it is just a matter of opinion, some people like onions, some people hate onions. The best thing to do is to pick one and stick with it (and enforce it across the team if there is one)

Comment: @alexanderb I have included the overheads in my answer that show which is faster based on my profiling test.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I disagree with Darin: they're *not* equivalent in terms of performance. The latter version has to create a new array, and `ToList` will then copy it into the new list. The collection initializer version is equivalent to:

```
var tmp = new List<int>();
tmp.Add(1);
tmp.Add(2);
tmp.Add(3);
var ints = tmp;
```

Assuming the list starts off with a large enough buffer, that won't require any further allocation - although it *will* involve a few method calls. If you do this for a very *large* number of items, then it will require *more* allocations than the `ToList` version, because it will copy the items as it goes.

The performance difference *is* likely to be negligible, but it's non-zero (and not *clearly* better in either direction - there are fewer calls in the array version, but more allocation).

I would concentrate more on style than performance unless you have a reason to suspect that the difference is significant, in which case you should *measure* rather than just guessing.

Personally I prefer the first form - I think it makes it clearer that you're using a list right from the start. Another alternative would be to write your own static class:

```
public static class Lists
{
    public static List<T> Of<T>(T item0)
    {
        return new List<T> { item0 };
    }

    public static List<T> Of<T>(T item0, T item1)
    {
        return new List<T> { item0, item1 };
    }

    public static List<T> Of<T>(T item0, T item1, T item2)
    {
        return new List<T> { item0, item1, item2 };
    }

    ... as many times as you really care about, then ...

    public static List<T> Of<T>(params T[] items)
    {
        return items.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
var ints = Lists.Of(1);
var ints = Lists.Of(1, 2, 3);
var ints = Lists.Of(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8); // Use the params version
```

This still makes it clear that you're using lists, but takes advantage of type inference.

You may well consider it overkill though :)

Comment: 1+. That is what I wanted to say! A lot of array copying happening and it is **not free**.

Comment: Absolutely, it won't create twice the items required neither perform additional operations. The fact is that this difference is so slight that you won't worry about it when initializing lists just once, but they can differ over time if you instantiate them a lot of times. But we're talking about small differences in any case.

Comment: if I good understand, he mean, that first version is better perform when a source data is not huge, because of reallocation (new allocation is twice as large + copy data)

Comment: @alexanderb: Not necessarily - there's less allocation and less copying involved in the collection initializer version (for small numbers of elements), but more calls to `Add`, each of which has to check whether it needs to expand, etc.

Answer (score 13):

Setting aside the difference between the two from a performance perspective, the former expresses what you are trying to achieve in a better way.

Consider expressing the code in English:

> declare a list of strings with these contents

And

> declare an array of strings with these contents and then convert it into a list of strings

To me, the first seems more natural. Although I acknowledge the second may be better for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought just a second before I read your answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Example 1 (var ints = new List { 1, 2, 3};): Provides a 31.5% overhead (Eumerable.ToList) and List.Add() causes a 8.7% overhead.

Where as example 2:  Causes a 11.8% overhead on List.ctor and a 5% for Ensure Capacity.

(Results from Red Gate ANTS Performance Profiler)

You can see that var ints = new List { 1, 2, 3}; has more operations to perform via the disassembly

```
 var intsx = new[] {1, 2, 3}.ToList();
0000003f  mov         edx,3 
00000044  mov         ecx,60854186h 
00000049  call        FFF5FD70 
0000004e  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax 
00000051  lea         ecx,[ebp-50h] 
00000054  mov         edx,872618h 
00000059  call        61490806 
0000005e  lea         eax,[ebp-50h] 
00000061  push        dword ptr [eax] 
00000063  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch] 
00000066  call        614908E3 
0000006b  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch] 
0000006e  call        dword ptr ds:[008726D8h] 
00000074  mov         dword ptr [ebp-54h],eax 
00000077  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-54h] 
0000007a  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax 

 var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
0000007d  mov         ecx,60B59894h 
00000082  call        FFF5FBE0 
00000087  mov         dword ptr [ebp-58h],eax 
0000008a  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-58h] 
0000008d  call        60805DB0 
00000092  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-58h] 
00000095  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax 
00000098  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
0000009b  mov         edx,1 
000000a0  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
000000a2  call        608070C0 
000000a7  nop 
000000a8  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
000000ab  mov         edx,2 
000000b0  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
000000b2  call        608070C0 
000000b7  nop 
000000b8  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
000000bb  mov         edx,3 
000000c0  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
000000c2  call        608070C0 
000000c7  nop 
000000c8  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
000000cb  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax 
        }
```

Comment: What do these `call`s do? what are their costs?

Comment: I don't have any profiling tools installed to give the accurate costs, this is the raw output from the disassembly showing you how many operations are performed for both examples in the question.  Will install and edit.

Comment: @L.B updated my answer to provide the costs you were looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I guess in the first case elements are automatically added to the list while in the second one first an array is created then it is iterated and every element is added to the list.

While probably second one will be optimized to avoid a real array creation it is worth noticing that if this operation is done inside a loop **you probably twice the object allocation amount** (unless it's straightly optimized) with no real need to do that.

You should check bytecode to be sure of it.

I'm not fond of C# internals though so take this with care!

Answer (score 1):

I like the first versions. But regarding perfomance I think the best is to use the array and define specifically the number of elements is going to be if of course this can be possible:

```
var x = new int[3] { 1, 3, 3 }.ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think explicitly specifying the array size adds anything.  The compiler can determine it via static analysis; and the `List<int>` will be created at whatever size the constructor prefers in either case.